# "font-family: sans-serif" appears in italics in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have this snippet in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
body<-->{
  font-family: sans-serif
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
Text
</body>
```

This comes out OK on Firefox and IE, but it comes out in italics in Chrome.  What is going on?  There doesn't seem to be a way of stopping it.

For that matter this text that I'm now typing also comes out in italics.

Comment: Please use a css file, with all of your styles.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a Google search below reveals that this is a font problem in Chrome.

You'll need to read a little further for solutions:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20chrome%20all%20italics